# Validation data leads to training data in keras.fit using TFRecordDataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to use TFRecords in order to train a model on ImageNet (code below). All is well, and training goes just fine, except that validation seems to be performed on the training set and not the validation set. 
I tested this by dumbing the training set down and doing nothing to the validation set, which led to both training and validation accuracy being 100%.

When I use fit_generator and flow_from_directory there is no such issue.

This is how I create the TFRecordDatasets:

```py
class ImageNetTFRecordDataset:
    def __init__(self, dir, batch_size):
        self._dir = dir
        self._batch_size = batch_size

    @staticmethod
    def _parse_function(proto):
        # read image
        keys_to_features = {'image/encoded': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
                            'image/class/label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)}

        # Load one example
        parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(proto, keys_to_features)

        # Turn your saved image string into an array
        parsed_features['image/encoded'] = tf.image.decode_jpeg(parsed_features['image/encoded'])

        parsed_features['image/encoded'] = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(parsed_features['image/encoded'], tf.float32)
        parsed_features['image/encoded'] = tf.image.per_image_standardization(parsed_features['image/encoded'])

        return parsed_features['image/encoded'], parsed_features["image/class/label"]

    def create_dataset(self):

        dir_files = os.listdir(self._dir)
        dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset([os.path.join(self._dir, f) for f in dir_files])

        # This dataset will go on forever
        dataset = dataset.repeat()

        # Set the number of datapoints you want to load and shuffle
        # dataset = dataset.shuffle(self._batch_size * 10)

        # Maps the parser on every filepath in the array. You can set the number of parallel loaders here
        dataset = dataset.map(self._parse_function, num_parallel_calls=8)

        # Set the batchsize
        dataset = dataset.batch(self._batch_size)

        dataset = dataset.prefetch(4)

        # Create an iterator
        iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

        # Create your tf representation of the iterator
        image, label = iterator.get_next()

        # Bring your picture back in shape
        image = tf.reshape(image, [-1, 224, 224, 3])

        # Create a one hot array for your labels
        label = tf.one_hot(label, 1000)

        return image, label
```

And this is how I train the model:

```py
train_dataset = ImageNetTFRecordDataset(train_dir, BATCH_SIZE)
val_dataset = ImageNetTFRecordDataset(val_dir, BATCH_SIZE)
x, y = train_dataset.create_dataset()
x_val, y_val = val_dataset.create_dataset()

model = get_model(x)  # this model's first layer is Input(tensor=x)
model.compile(optimizer=OPTIMIZER, loss=categorical_crossentropy,
                  metrics=get_metrics(), target_tensors=[y])

model.fit(epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=1, validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
                  steps_per_epoch=150, callbacks=get_callbacks(),
                  validation_steps=VAL_STEPS)
```

Any ideas where things go wrong? Why does the validation part feed off the training set?

Comment: I've done that before but I never used `target_tensors`. Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: How can you do this without `target_tensors`? It gives an error.